# Wrapping a groovy script into an executable. E.g. using launch4j

Tags: groovy, executable, launch4j

I have written a small groovy application that I would like to package into a windows and linux executable

I have previously used launch4j for a java application for this, but is it even possible to build an executable from a groovy script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compile your script(s) with `groovyc`, that will result in a class with the same name as your script name. The class contains a `public static void main` method that runs the script code.

I.e. to execute with java you'd do something like:

```
java -cp groovy-all.jar MyScript <arguments>
```

The resulting classes can be packaged with launch4j. Just remember to include the necessary groovy jar's.